# Why rvalue reference member would be const?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

I am trying to write a move constructor for a structure but I can't understand why I fail to call the move constructor of structure member:

```
#include <memory>

struct C
{
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> mVector;
    size_t                 mSize;

    C() = default;

    C(C &&temp)
    : mVector(temp.mVector)
    , mSize(temp.mSize)
    {}    
};
```

When I compile this I get:

```
gcc -c TempTest.cpp
TempTest.cpp: In constructor 'C::C(C&&)':
TempTest.cpp:9:23: error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp [], _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp [], _Dp>&) [with _Tp = int; _Dp = std::default_delete<int []>]'
9 |     , mSize(temp.mSize)
  |                       ^
In file included from c:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.3.0/memory:83,
             from TempTest.cpp:1:
c:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/10.3.0/bits/unique_ptr.h:723:7: note: declared here
 723 |       unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
     |       ^~~~~~~~~~
```

Because in contructor `temp` is a rvalue reference, it is non-const so `temp.mVector` should be non-const and should call the `unique_ptr` move constructor but instead it calls the copy constructor which is deleted. Any idea where is the error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why rvalue reference member would be const?

Don't assume that it's `const`.  You should assume that `unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&)` is merely the *best match*, from the available constructors.

> Because in constructor `temp` is a rvalue reference

Surprise!  It is **not** an r-value reference.

The variable `temp` is *bound* to an r-value, when the constructor is called.  And now that it's a named variable, it's no longer a "temporary".  It has become an l-value.

Since you know that the value **was** an r-value when the constructor was called, you can safely move the members, converting them back to an r-value.

```
C(C &&temp)
: mVector(std::move(temp.mVector))
//        ^^^^^^^^^ We know that temp CAME FROM an r-value,
//                  so it can safely be moved.
, mSize(temp.mSize)
{}
```

Answer (score 2):

try to run the following code and everything become clear:

```
struct Test
{
    Test(){}
    Test(const Test& r)
    {
        std::cout << "i am using the copy constructor :) " << std::endl;
    }
    
    Test(Test&& r)
    {
        std::cout << "I require std::move to be selected as possible overload.." << std::endl;
    }
    
};

int main()
{
    Test first;
    Test second(first);
    
    Test third(std::move(second));
    return 0;
}
```

std::move helps to select the right constructor overload by passing a r-value reference (Test&&) to the constructor.
In your case, the compiler is selecting the copy constructor even if your vector isn't const, just because it is considered the best match (an implicit cast to a const reference is preferred to an implicit cast to a r-value reference, since the second one, differently from the first, may modify the value)  adding a std::move you can select the right constructor and solve your issue.

```
#include <memory>

struct C
{
    std::unique_ptr<int[]> mVector;
    size_t                 mSize;

    C() = default;

    C(C &&temp)
    : mVector(std::move(temp.mVector))
    , mSize(temp.mSize)
    {}    
};
```